# Descargar Archivo PDF Api Axios React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objeto

actualmente estoy tratando de descargar un archivo PDF proveída por la API con la que estoy trabajando, no he tenido Exito, he logrado descargar el archivo PDF pero sin datos, en otro código la respuesta es blob no es una función, quisiera preguntarles cual es la forma correcta de bajar el archivo.
Apresiaria mucho su ayuda, de ante mano gracias.

```
const GenerarTicket = id =>{
    let enlace = `ticket/${id}`;
    clienteAxios.get(enlace,{
      responseType: 'blob',
    }).then(response=>{
    response.blob().then(blob=>{
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    let a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'Ticket.pdf';
                    a.click();
    }) 

    }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
    }
```

```
const GenerarTicket = id =>{
    let enlace = `ticket/${id}`;
   MethodGet(enlace,{
      responseType: 'blob',
    }).then(res=>{
     FileDownload(res.data, 'Ticket.pdf');

    }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente falta un poco mas de código pero con esto quedo

```
const GenerarTicket = id =>{
    let enlace = `ticket/${id}`;
    clienteAxios.get(enlace,{
      responseType: 'blob',
    }).then(response=>{
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href= url
      link.setAttribute('download','Ticket.pdf')
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      link.click();

    }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error);
    });
  }
```